# Could not find imported resource during MuleSoft build

Tags: mule, mulesoft, mule4, mule-maven-plugin

I have mule-artifact.json containing

```
"configs": [
   "global.xml", "flow.xml"
],
```

In global.xml I have

```
<import file="connectors/global-connectors.xml" />
```

After I've updated

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.mule.tools.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>mule-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${mule.maven.plugin.version}</version>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <configuration>
        <classifier>mule-application</classifier>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

from 3.5.4 to 4.0.0 I have the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.mule.tools.maven:mule-maven-plugin:4.0.0:process-classes (default-process-classes) on project mule-project: Fail to compile: Could not find imported resource 'connectors/global-connectors.xml' -> [Help 1]
```

My maven is 3.9.5.
I build project via mvn clean package -DskipTests.

If I insert contents from connectors/global-connectors.xml to global.xml I have another import error, if I remove another import then build is successful.

I didn't find what is changed in mule-maven-plugin 4.0.0.

Comment: Why do you have `"configs"` configured in mule-artifact.json? Does something change if you remove it?

Comment: If I leave only 
{
  "minMuleVersion": "4.4.0"
}
which is the case then it fails as well

Comment: Where in your project is the imported file?

Comment: It's in the src/main/mule/connectors/global-connectors.xml
I tried to put it in the src/main/mule/
But still the same error.

Comment: Seems like it's a bug and I reach out contact mule-maven-plugin developers. Because idk how is it possible, imported file is in target folder, everything is okay, but I can create an empty new file in the root, import that file and it still won't build. Looks like nonsense. 
I've just created a new project via newest Anypoint Studio and do the same (created a few xml files and imported them) — still nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the global-connectors.xml is correctly placed in the resource path as expected by the Mule application. In Mule 4, the default resource path is **src/main/resources**. If your connectors are not in this directory, the plugin might not be able to locate them.